# Angular 2 Embed sub components in a View depending on a model

Tags: angular, dart

How do I create a new Component(View) that contains other Components depending on a Model (written in dart)?

Item (super class):

```
@Component(selector: 'item')
@View(template: '<div/>')
class Item {}
```

ImageItem & ButtonItem (sub classes):

```
@Component(selector: 'image-item')
@View(template: '''
  <div>
    <img src="http://localhost:8082/images/test.png"/>
  </div>''')

class ImageItem extends Item {
  String selector = 'image-item';
  ImageItem() : super() {}
}

@Component(selector: 'button-item')
@View(template: '''
  <div>
    <button type="button"/>
  </div>''')   
class ButtonItem extends Item {
  String selector = 'button-item';
  ButtonItem() : super() {}
}
```

Simple component/model that contains a list of components:

```
@Component(selector: 'app')
@View(
templateUrl: 'app.html',
directives: const [Item, ImageItem, ButtonItem, NgFor, NgSwitch, NgSwitchDefault, NgSwitchWhen])
class App {
  List<Item> items = [new ButtonItem(), new ImageItem(), new ImageItem()];
}
```

Now I would like to create the app.html view depending on the items list. Is there a better solution then using NgSwitch?

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li *ng-for="#item of items; #i = index" >
            <div [ng-switch]="item[i].selector">
             <template ng-switch-when="button-item">
                 <button-item>{{item.selector}}</button-item>
             </template>
             <template ng-switch-when="image-item">
                 <image-item>{{item.selector}}</image-item>
             </template>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
--> does not work, don't know why
```

Comment: Nope! That is pretty much the best way to do it.

Comment: Also faced with this issue, investigated. Indeed, have to use switch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a use case for the [DynamicComponentLoader](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html) that allows to dynamically inject components in the component tree.

Once the component is injected in the tree, it becomes just a component like any other. Here is an [example](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f0e962c55eddd6827095c183b357d8268352144e/modules/angular2_material/src/components/dialog/dialog.ts) of how to use it.

Comment: How can I bind data from parent component to a child that was inserted using DynamicComponentLoader?

Comment: Warning : Dynamic Component Loader is now deprecated. From the documentation : use ComponentResolver and ViewContainerRef instead.

Comment: is there any example for ComponentResolver and ViewContainerRef.?